# when retrieving data a part of it doesn't appear because of the sign " ' "

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql database using php and mysqli 
but when the result show up there is some fields that are not complete for example:
the field in the database is: domaine de l'agricultule
but when it show up is like: domaine de l

```
    echo "<input type='text' name='domaine' size='80' dir='ltr'    value='{$row['domaine']}'/>";
```

help please where i the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is the html created with that value becomes invalid due to the apostrophe, so you need to encode it like so:

```
 echo "<input type='text' name='domaine' size='80' dir='ltr' value='".htmlspecialchars($row['domaine'], ENT_QUOTES)."' />";
```

you could change value to use **"**  (double quotes), but that could still cause problems depending on the potential values of domaine

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Unless you set the `ENT_QUOTES` flag , htmlspecialchars will not encode `'`

Comment: @Davina have you used the 'edited' version with the ENT_QUOTES flag?